# How to use AbstractUser to customize django User model

Tags: python, django

I am working on a Django project and I am trying to customize the Django User model by inheriting AbstractUser in my models.py but when I run my server I get this error message.
**AttributeError: Manager isn’t available; ‘auth.User’ has been swapped for ‘django_starter_app.User’** 
What I am doing wrong here? below is my code 
**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

# Create your models here.

class User(AbstractUser):

    STUDENT = 1

    TEACHER = 2

    SECRETARY = 3

    SUPERVISOR = 4

    SITE_ADMIN = 5

    USER_TYPE_CHOICES = (

        (STUDENT, 'student'),

        (TEACHER, 'teacher'),

        (SECRETARY, 'secretary'),

        (SUPERVISOR, 'supervisor'),

        (SITE_ADMIN, 'site_admin'),

    )

    user_type = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=USER_TYPE_CHOICES)

    phone = models.CharField(max_length=12, blank=True, null=True)

    address = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
```

**on settings.py**

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'django_starter_app.User'
```

Comment: Advise not doing this and just creating a profile model with a one to one relationship with the user model

Comment: I am doing this because I want to implement multiple user types as sujested by this post https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/01/18/how-to-implement-multiple-user-types-with-django.html#strategies

Comment: Can you try creating your custom class with some other name like `class UserProfile(AbstractUser)` and also change your AUTH_USER_MODEL setting variable as accordingly.

Comment: I have done that befor if gave the same error

Comment: You can do the same thing with a related profile field without risking messing up the auth sysem. Django docs explicitly recommend against doing this unless you really know what You’re doing.

Comment: The error you’re encountering is because you’ve already migrated and you’re trying to swap the user model. This isn’t straightforward. If you’re going to use a custom user, life is easier if you do it before first migration

Comment: @bryan60 I created the models and added to settings before migrating